# What are the significant changes of data base in moodle from 1.9.18 to 1.9.19?

Tags: database, content-management-system, moodle

I have coded an external CMS for Moodle 1.9.18 to register users with packages of courses.

Works as described next:

1. I create three kind of users, students, non-editing teachers and editing teachers depending of the course they're going to be enrolled.
2. I create groups in order to keep isolated the student users for their teachers, so teachers can evaluate them.
3. I register the group to the courses the users have access to.

My question popped up when we realized moodle 1.9.18 can't handle the amount of courses we have created so we need to upgrade it.

Before getting involved in this matter I wanted to ask someone who knows better data bases in moodle.

Eventually, I'll have to test the upgrade against the external CMS but if I have any hands up before I get into it that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are none.

In Moodle we try to avoid making database schema changes on stable releases, so it would be very unusual to see differences. However to confirm this statement, I verified this by looking for differences in install.xml files (where moodle stores its schema definitions) between the releases and you'll not there are none:

```
git diff v1.9.18..v1.9.19  --name-only
enrol/mnet/enrol.php
lib/environmentlib.php
mod/data/lib.php
mod/data/view.php
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/addquizchain.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/analysistable.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/clickreporting.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/clickreporttable.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/forceplugins.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/index.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/mediaplayers.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/mods.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/navigation.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/outputformat.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/removegradeitem.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/reportcontent.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/reportformat.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/responsestable.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/shownextquiz.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/studentfeedback.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/help/hotpot/updatequizchain.html
mod/hotpot/lang/en_utf8/hotpot.php
mod/hotpot/lib.php
mod/hotpot/restorelib.php
mod/hotpot/view.php
question/format/hotpot/format.php
version.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there any relevant code change, since it just seems a bugfix release. In this page you can find additional details: [Moodle 1.9.19 release notes](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Moodle_1.9.19_release_notes).

The 2.x branch on the contrary has lots of changes under the hood. But how many courses are you going to create? Moodle is capable to hold *a big* number of courses... (tens of thousands of courses, have a look [here](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Installations_30000_plus)).